# terraform init Failed to query available provider packages

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

i've tf file "tes.tf" with the following contains

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.73"
    }
  }
}
provider "aws" {
  region     = "eu-west-1"
}
resource "aws-instance" "myec2" {
  ami = "ami-01efa4023f0f3a042"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    "Name" = "fahrial-ec2-terraform"
  }
}
```

but when i try to run "terraform init" getting the following error, does anyone know what the cause is?

```
# terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/aws from the dependency lock file
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/aws-instance...
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/aws v3.73.0
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/aws-instance: provider registry
│ registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws-instance
│
│ All modules should specify their required_providers so that external consumers will get the correct providers when using a
│ module. To see which modules are currently depending on hashicorp/aws-instance, run the following command:
│     terraform providers
```

Comment: You have made a typo: `aws-instance` should be `aws_instance`.

Comment: @MarkoE, is right man!

Comment: Yes you're right,  thanks @MarkoE

Answer (score 2):

There is an error with resource name named `aws-instance`. It should be `aws_instance`, with underscore.

You can take a look to registry:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance